# Parity of self-linking

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

For a class $x$ in $H_{2k}$ of a 4k-manifold $M$, the self-intersection $x.x$ agrees mod 2 with the cap product of $x$ with the Wu class $v_{2k}$. If instead $x$ is a torsion element of $H_{2k}$ of a (4k+1)-manifold, the self-linking of $x$ defines an element of order 2. Is this equal to the inner product of $x$ with $v_{2k}$?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. For any space $M$ there is defined a torsion linking pairing on the $Q/Z$-coefficient cohomology groups
$$L:H^m(M;Q/Z) \times H^n(M;Q/Z) \to H^{m+n+1}(M;Q/Z);(a,b) \mapsto \delta a \cup b = a \cup \delta b$$
with $\delta:H^p(M;Q/Z)\to H^{p+1}(M)$ the Bockstein coboundaries for $p=m,n$, such that $$\text{image}(\delta)=\text{kernel}(H^{p+1}(M)\to H^{p+1}(M;Q))=\text{torsion}(H^{p+1}(M)).$$ 
This pairing is $(-1)^{(m+1)(n+1)}$-symmetric
$$L(a,b)=(-1)^{(m+1)(n+1)}L(b,a) \in H^{m+n+1}(M;Q/Z).$$
If $M$ is a closed connected oriented $(m+n+1)$-dimensional manifold this gives a  $(-1)^{(m+1)(n+1)}$-symmetric torsion linking pairing
$$L:H^m(M;Q/Z) \times H^n(M;Q/Z) \to H^{m+n+1}(M;Q/Z)=Q/Z$$
which induces the usual nonsingular linking pairing on the torsion groups
$$L:{\rm torsion}(H^{m+1}(M)) \times {\rm torsion}(H^{n+1}(M)) \to Q/Z.$$
For a $(4k+1)$-dimensional manifold $M$ and $m=n=2k$ this linking pairing is skew-symmetric. The self-linking defines a linear map
$$H^{2k}(M;Q/Z) \to Q/Z~ ;~ a \mapsto L(a,a)=0~\text{or}~1/2$$
which is represented by the image of the Wu class $v_{2k}(M) \in H^{2k}(M;Z_2)$ under the injection $Z_2 \to Q/Z~;~1 \mapsto 1/2$. The Poincare dual of a torsion homology class $x \in H_{2k}(M)$ is of the form $\delta a\in H^{2k+1}(M)$ for some $a \in H^{2k}(M;Q/Z)$ and
$$\text{self-linking}(x)=L(a,a)= \delta a \cup v_{2k}(M) = \langle x,v_{2k}(M) \rangle \in Z_2\subset Q/Z.$$
[Subsequent editing 17.1.2015]
On page 49 of the 1976 AMS Memoir "A product formula for surgery obstructions" by John Morgan it is stated without proof that for a $(4k+1)$-dimensional manifold $M$
$$L(x,x) ~=~\langle x,v_{2k}(M)\rangle \in Z_2 \subset Q/Z~{\rm for}~ x \in {\rm torsion}(H_{2k}(M))~.$$
It must be confessed that the above "proof" does not go into sufficient detail. So here is a direct proof of Morgan's formula. Let $C=C(M)$ be the chain complex of $M$, $C^*={\rm Hom}_Z(C(M),Z)$ the cochain complex, and consider the cup$_0$ chain map and the cup$_1$ chain homotopy
$$\phi_0 ~=~ [M]\cap -~ :~ C^{4k+1-*} \to C~,~\phi_1
 ~:~ \phi_0~ \simeq~ T\phi_0~ :~ C^{4k+1-*} \to  C$$
given by the evaluation of an extended diagonal chain map on a fundamental cycle $[M] \in C_{4k+1}$, with $T$ the signed transposition involution on ${\rm Hom}_Z(C^*,C) = C\otimes_ZC$.  In particular there are defined $Z$-module morphisms
$$\phi_0~:~C^{2k+1} \to C_{2k}~,~ \phi'_0:C^{2k} \to  C_{2k+1}~,~ \phi_1~:~C^{2k+1} \to C_{2k+1}$$
such that
$$d \phi'_0~=~ \phi_0 d^* ~:~ C^{2k} \to C_{2k}~,$$
$$\phi_0 + \phi'{_0}^*~ =~ d\phi_1+\phi_1 d^*~ :~ C^{2k+1} \to C_{2k}$$
$$d\phi_0 + (d\phi_0)^*~ =~ d\phi_1d^*~ :~ C^{2k} \to C_{2k}~.$$
The intersection number of cohomology classes $x \in H^{2k+1}(M)$, $y \in H^{2k}(M)$
is given by
$$\langle x \cup y,[M]\rangle ~=~\phi_0(x)(y) \in Z~ .$$
Also
$$\langle Sq^{2k}(x),[M]\rangle ~ =~ \phi_1(x)(x)~=~\langle v_{2k}(M) \cup x,[M]\rangle  \in Z_2~.$$
The linking number of torsion cohomology classes  $x,z \in {\rm torsion}(H^{2k+1}(M))$ is
$$L(x,z)~ =~ \phi_0(d^*)^{-1}(x)(z) \in  Q/Z~.$$
In view of the formal identity
$$\phi_0(d^*)^{-1} + (\phi_0(d^*)^{-1})^*~ =~ \phi_1$$
the self-linking number of $x=z$
$$L(x,x)~ =~ \phi_0(d^*)^{-1}(x)(x) \in Q/Z$$
is represented by a rational number $r \in Q$ such that
$$2r~ =~ \phi_1(x)(x) \in Z \subset Q$$
so that $r=0$ or $1/2 \in Q/Z$, according to the value of $\phi_1(x)(x) \in Z_2$, and
$$L(x,x)~ =~ \langle v_{2k}(M) \cup x,[M]\rangle  \in Z_2 \subset Q/Z~.$$
For a fuller account of the generalized Wu-Thom relationship between the symmetric structure on a manifold (resp. geometric Poincare complex) and the Wu classes of the normal bundle (resp. Spivak normal fibration) see section 9 of my 1980 Proc. LMS paper *The algebraic theory of surgery II.* http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/ats2.pdf 
For a fuller account of the relationship between intersection and linking numbers and the Wu classes check out section 3.3  of my 1981 Princeton book *Exact sequences in the algebraic theory of surgery* http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/exacsrch.pdf